# Graphics is blank when trying to turn anti-aliasing off for a bitmap (C#)

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap

**What I'm trying to do:**

Since in my bitmaps there are some unwanted white edges around the picture that result from anti-aliasing as pointed out from another user from stackoverflow.
I'm trying to convert an image that's inputted into a bitmap, convert bitmap into a Graphics object so that I can set the Smooth Mode to none, and then finally convert that Graphics object to a bitmap so that it can be copied by the user after setting it to the clipboard. I'm not sure if this is a good way of getting rid anti-aliasing in bitmaps but I'm definitely interested in improvements and suggestions.

**The issue I'm facing:**

The result of the image after is completely blank and does not contain any of the pixels that are previously found in the original bitmap. Here's the result:
[image: Example picture of the result.]

This issue applies to all pictures no matter what their format is.

**My code:**

```
    public PicGen(PictureBox pictureBox)
    { 
        Clipboard.Clear();
        Bitmap firstImage = new(pictureBox.Image, pictureBox.Width, pictureBox.Height);
        
        
        RectangleF cloneRect = new RectangleF(0, 0, firstImage.Width, firstImage.Height);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat format = firstImage.PixelFormat;
        Bitmap cloneBitmap = firstImage.Clone(cloneRect, format);
        Graphics AntiARemover = Graphics.FromImage(cloneBitmap);
        AntiARemover.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None;
        Bitmap finalImg = new(52, 52, AntiARemover);
        Clipboard.SetImage(finalImg);


        Color backColorBottom = firstImage.GetPixel(0, 0);
        firstImage.ReplaceColor(backColorBottom, Color.FromArgb(54, 57, 63));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Bitmap finalImg = new(52, 52, AntiARemover);

From the documentation for this bitmap constructor:

> The new Bitmap that this method creates takes its horizontal and vertical resolution from the DpiX and DpiY properties of g, respectively.

If you want create a new image with the content from another you need to call one of the [DrawImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) methods. You should also dispose your graphics object, and any temporary bitmaps you may use.

```
using var finalImg = new Bitmap(52,52);
using var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(finalImg);
graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None;
graphics.DrawImage(cloneBitmap)
```

However, edge artifacts typically occur when combining two images using an alpha channel, see [Premultiplied alpha](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/WinUI3/html/PremultipliedAlpha.htm). In your example I can only see one input image, so I'm really not sure what it is you are actually trying to do. If you need to convert to premultiplied alpha you can use the following code to convert the color for each pixel

```
premultiplied.R = (byte)(straight.R * straight.A / 255);
premultiplied.G = (byte)(straight.G * straight.A / 255);
premultiplied.B = (byte)(straight.B * straight.A / 255);
premultiplied.A = straight.A;
```

Comment: I'm not using two input images, only one. I'm sorry if my goal wasn't clear in the post. I'm trying to change the background of an image from one color to another. The images mainly consist of empty backgrounds with an object in the middle. After the color has been replaced, there are some very noticeable white artifacts surrounding the object. I have been told that it was due to anti-aliasing, that's why I'm trying to convert the bitmap to a graphics, so that I can turn the smoothing mode off. Original(https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2tUe.png), After the code(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzlFS.png)

Comment: Do you think that is a good proper way to remove the white artifacts or should I try taking a different route?

Comment: @AhmedSherif The simple replace color-method is only possible if the source image has a sharp transition from the background to foreground. In effect using one specific color as a 1 bit alpha channel. But if the image is already created you cannot fix it, At best you could do something like chroma keying, but that will require a constant hue background that does not occur in the foreground and considerably more complex algorithms to make it look good. But you should probably post an example of the image you are trying to fix.